# Too many method references - using AppEngine SDK in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I'm using App Engine Endpoints for my Android application. The problem is that I get the following error after using Endpoints and adding another SDK:

```
trouble writing output: Too many method references: 116924; max is 65536.
You may try using --multi-dex option.
References by package:
    23 com.google.appengine.api
  1540 com.google.appengine.api.appidentity
    22 com.google.appengine.api.backends
  1421 com.google.appengine.api.blobstore
     4 com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.proto2api
   795 com.google.appengine.api.capabilities
   352 com.google.appengine.api.channel
  2374 com.google.appengine.api.datastore
  5231 com.google.appengine.api.files
  2950 com.google.appengine.api.images
   174 com.google.appengine.api.log
   722 com.google.appengine.api.mail
     4 com.google.appengine.api.mail.proto2api
    10 com.google.appengine.api.mail.stdimpl
  3711 com.google.appengine.api.memcache
    48 com.google.appengine.api.memcache.stdimpl
  2178 com.google.appengine.api.modules
    38 com.google.appengine.api.oauth
  1497 com.google.appengine.api.prospectivesearch
     8 com.google.appengine.api.prospectivesearch.proto2api
    27 com.google.appengine.api.quota
    14 com.google.appengine.api.rdbms
   606 com.google.appengine.api.search
    79 com.google.appengine.api.search.checkers
   381 com.google.appengine.api.search.query
  3724 com.google.appengine.api.socket
     4 com.google.appengine.api.socket.proto2api
  5443 com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue
     4 com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.proto2api
   966 com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch
    43 com.google.appengine.api.users
    44 com.google.appengine.api.utils
  1463 com.google.appengine.api.xmpp
     4 com.google.appengine.api.xmpp.proto2api
  5480 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.appengine.api.search
  1243 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base
     7 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.internal
  8524 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.collect
   103 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.escape
   379 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.flags
   642 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.hash
     1 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.html
   578 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.io
   103 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.math
    39 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.net
     2 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.parameterset
   556 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.primitives
    36 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.util
   753 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent
     5 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.xml
   290 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.base
   177 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.base.shell
  1348 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol
  1752 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.proto
     8 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.proto.proto2api
     4 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.proto2
    24 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.net.base
    25 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.net.util.error
 10402 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf
   191 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.bridge
    12 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.contrib.descriptor_pool
    51 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.contrib.htmlform
   384 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.downgraded
  1540 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protos.gdata.proto2api
     8 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protos.proto2.bridge
  3173 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.storage.onestore.v3.proto2api
   407 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.antlr.runtime
   368 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.antlr.runtime.debug
    43 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.antlr.runtime.misc
   422 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.antlr.runtime.tree
  2015 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.joda.time
   268 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.joda.time.base
   858 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.joda.time.chrono
   120 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.joda.time.convert
   533 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.joda.time.field
   540 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.joda.time.format
   178 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.joda.time.tz
    26 com.google.appengine.spi
  1521 com.google.appengine.tools.appstats
    39 com.google.appengine.tools.compilation
  6283 com.google.apphosting.api
  1971 com.google.apphosting.api.logservice
     4 com.google.apphosting.api.logservice.proto2api
   739 com.google.apphosting.api.proto2api
  1688 com.google.apphosting.api.search
     8 com.google.apphosting.base
   207 com.google.apphosting.client.datastoreservice.app
   102 com.google.apphosting.client.datastoreservice.app.mobile
  1782 com.google.apphosting.client.datastoreservice.mobile
  2343 com.google.apphosting.client.datastoreservice.proto
    51 com.google.apphosting.client.serviceapp
  6714 com.google.apphosting.datastore
   705 com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi
    59 com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet
   785 com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc
   532 com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal
     5 com.google.httputil
     1 com.google.inject
     1 com.google.inject.util
     1 com.google.net.base
    39 com.google.net.rpc
     6 com.google.net.rpc.impl
     6 com.google.net.rpc3.client
     1 com.google.net.rpc3.impl
     3 com.google.net.rpc3.impl.compatibility
     1 com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server
     5 com.google.net.rpc3.server
     1 com.google.net.ssl
  6099 com.google.protos.cloud.sql
    10 com.google.storage.onestore
  2287 com.google.storage.onestore.v3
     3 default
     5 it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.ints
     6 java.awt.datatransfer
    10 java.beans
   226 java.io
   438 java.lang
    13 java.lang.ref
    36 java.lang.reflect
    28 java.math
    73 java.net
    68 java.nio
     7 java.nio.channels
    16 java.nio.charset
    16 java.security
    40 java.sql
    34 java.text
   520 java.util
   129 java.util.concurrent
    26 java.util.concurrent.atomic
    37 java.util.concurrent.locks
    14 java.util.logging
    18 java.util.regex
     5 java.util.zip
   163 javax.activation
    13 javax.annotation.processing
    49 javax.cache
     1 javax.lang.model
    19 javax.lang.model.element
     4 javax.lang.model.type
     4 javax.lang.model.util
   405 javax.mail
    59 javax.mail.event
   502 javax.mail.internet
   108 javax.mail.search
    45 javax.mail.util
     1 javax.net.ssl
     6 javax.servlet
    26 javax.servlet.http
     2 javax.tools
     3 org.antlr.stringtemplate
    23 org.apache.geronimo.mail.handlers
   190 org.apache.geronimo.mail.util
     4 org.xml.sax
     2 org.xml.sax.helpers
     6 sun.misc
```

As you can see, com.google.appengine is taking most of the method references. How can I limit it?

Comment: Are you using ProGuardy things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you hit the [65k method limit](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html), there are a few options you can do.

in your gradle file you can specify `minifyEnabled = true` and it will cut down unused resources and code.

you can also use the SDK build tools `21.1.X` that supports multi dex file creation using the dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

along with adding in `multiDexEnabled true` to your gradle. more information can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)